# Does anyone know how to call a ACPI method in C# on Windows?

Tags: c#, acpi

For example, there is an EPSW method, how should I call it in C#? Is there any relevant information?

[image]

OR

```
Method(EPSW, 1) {
...
}
```

Comment: Not from userspace, you can't. There may be system calls to ask the kernel to do it, but likely not a generic ACPI function. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I want to try to call the packaged acpi method provided by the BIOS to turn on power to a custom USB device.

Comment: sometimes there is custom WMI management interfaces provided by manufacturers of your hardware (for example `HP Client Management Interface`, we used it to remotly change BIOS passwords of our `HP` workstations)

Comment: @vasily.sib It's true, but for this method, they do not provide WMI management interfaces, thanks for your reply!

Comment: @vasily.sib I seem to find a way to call ACPI Method. Do you know how to call it in C#?  [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows-hardware/drivers/acpi/evaluating-a-control-method-that-takes-input-arguments)